# Elastic Search with Java

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am trying to connect to Elastic Search like this,

```
Transport client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(Settings.EMPTY).
                    addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 9200));
```

But I am getting following error when I run:-

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError: io.netty.util.concurrent.MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.newChild(Ljava/util/concurrent/Executor;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Lio/netty/util/concurrent/EventExecutor;
at io.netty.util.concurrent.MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.java:84)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.java:58)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.java:47)
at io.netty.channel.MultithreadEventLoopGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventLoopGroup.java:49)
```

My pom.xml is

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
            <artifactId>transport</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.1</version>
</dependency>
 <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.6.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Please help thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

I am guessing this could probably be because of the change in implementation at your end in terms of upgrading the version of elastic search from a version lower than 2.4 to current.

The right way to implement the above with [current version](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/5.2/transport-client.html) would be -

```
TransportClient client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(Settings.EMPTY)
        .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 9200));
```

While the implementation with and before [Version 2.3](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/2.3/transport-client.html) was as :

```
Client client = TransportClient.builder().build()
    .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("host1"), 9300))
    .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("host2"), 9300));
```

And I am going by the definition of [*AbstractMethodError* here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/AbstractMethodError.html)

> Thrown when an application tries to call an abstract method. Normally,
>   this error is caught by the compiler; **this error can only occur at run
>   time if the definition of some class has incompatibly changed since
>   the currently executing method was last compiled.**

For which I would also suggest you, to go through the `mvn dependency:tree` and `exclude` any other dependencies for the artifact `org.elasticsearch.client`.

Answer (score 1):

`9200` is the port of Elasticsearch REST API. To connect from a Java client, you should use port `9300`. I don't know why the stacktrace and error message are so unclear...

Comment: Damn, good catch, didn't even notice that.  +1 vote for you, and I updated my answer to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Your initialization syntax looks correct, and nothing in your pom screams JAR hell or any other conflicts, but there is one issue with how you have it:

Use the `TransportClient` object instead of a `Transport` object that you are attempting to use.

```
TransportClient client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(Settings.EMPTY).
                        addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 9300));
```

`Transport` is an Interface in the Elasticsearch repo, see  [here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/transport/Transport.java).  The Transport Client depends on the rest of Elasticsearch, see [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.elasticsearch.client/transport/5.2.2), and downloads it and adds it to your project's dependencies.  What this means, is that when you say `Transport` it...

1. Is not the TransportClient you're looking for.
2. You are inadvertently referring to a `Transport` Interface in Elasticsearch's main code.

Answer (score 0):

```
 //Try this method...
    TransportClient client = null;
    public Client getConnection(){
    if (client == null) {
                Settings settings = Settings.builder().put("cluster.name", 
           "elasticsearch").put("client.transport.sniff", true).build();
    try {
        // preparing client object...
    client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(settings).addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"),9300));
                } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

            return client;
```